# Using the mic as sound impact sensor

Tags: android, audio, android-sensors

I want to use the mic of an Android device as sound impact sensor (like in some music visulization projects).

Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJGM3PiYpqk

I wasn't able to find anything related here or via google.

Is this possible with as little delay as possible and without recording to a file?

Comment: You can record uncompressed PCM directly without saving the data to a file using the [AudioRecord API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html). You could also do the recording using OpenSL ES, which essentially is the same thing as using an `AudioRecord`, except that you skip the Java layer. I'm not sure whether the latency will be good enough for your purposes though, but the only way to find out is for your to prototype the idea.

Comment: Thanks, do you know a good tutorial/example for AudioRecord?
Im using MediaRecorder and getMaxAmplitude() right now but it would be great to check for other thing than just amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project with sound processing and I think there's something useful to you. As what I know, the phone capture the sound through the micro by sampling and then pcm (pulse code modulation) the signal to the value of amplitude. Our job is set the config for the recorder:

```
    int frequency = 8000;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int blockSize = 256;
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
```

And create new instances of the recorder with these config:

```
    AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
```

Then start recording with this:

```
    short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
    float[] toTransform = new float[blockSize];
    try {
        audioRecord.startRecording();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("Recording failed", e.toString());
    }
    while (check) {
            if(isCancelled()) break;
            int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
            // Your code goes here, buffer now has the value of amplitude of sound that you need.

            publishProgress(result);
        }
        try {
            audioRecord.stop();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("Stop failed", e.toString());
        }
```

The recording should be the thread or asynctask that run on background. I suggest using Asynctask to publish the result everytime the sound is captured. The check like the control variable of the recording. You can use button to control this.

It is another ideal that you don't use the sound's amplitude, you can transform the signal to frequency domain. But I think using amplitude is much easier